# How to substitute IoT Edge env variables in “deployment.template.json” in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-iot-edge, docker-secrets

I want to use Azure DevOps for IoT Edge project where some secrets should be passed through json file.
This is the fragment of the deployment.template.json file:

```
        "env": {
      "mappedFolder": { "value": "/temp" },
      "netatmoClientId": { "value": "${netatmoClientId}" },
      "netatmoClientSecret": { "value": "${netatmoClientSecret}" },
      "netatmoUsername": { "value": "${netatmoUsername}" },
      "netatmoPassword": { "value": "${netatmoPassword}" },
```

Locally everything works correctly. I have the .env file and the values in json will be replaced correctly during build.

How to use the same behavior with Azure DevOps?

I already declared devops pipeline variables but placeholders inside json file are not substituted from the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requirement can be achieved of using *Secret files* in Azure DevOps.

1. .env file with the secrets has to be uploaded into Azure Devops library "Secure files"
2. Adding task to pipeline "Download secure file" and pointing to the .env file

```
steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: 'Download secure file'
  inputs:
    secureFile: .env
```

3. Adding task to pipeline "Copy Files to" to copy the env file into working directory.

```
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: MyProjectName'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
    Contents: .env
    TargetFolder: MyProjectName
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops

Comment: Hi @sepp,

Thanks for sharing your experiences. Could you please mark your answer as the solution of this topic? This may be very helpful to other people who are looking for a solution for the similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this task [Replace Tokens](https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task#readme) in the Azure DevOps release pipeline.

**Step 1:** Update token prefix like this.

[image]

**Step 2**: Update your template like this.

```
"netatmoClientId": { "value": "$(netatmoClientId)" },
"netatmoClientSecret": { "value": "$(netatmoClientSecret}) },
"netatmoUsername": { "value": "$(netatmoUsername)" },
"netatmoPassword": { "value": "$(netatmoPassword)" }
```

**Step 3**: Define the above variables in Variable Groups or Release Pipeline Variables

**Step 4**: Use **Replace Tokens** task like below.

[image]